# Complex Types in DataTables without Converters

Tags: jsf, datatable, converters, el

I don't understand why my `dataTable` doesn't need a `Converter` here. Using only the code here, my `deleteAction` method is getting called with the complete object.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{gestionCat.lc}" var="c">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Nom</f:facet>
        #{c.nom}
    </p:column>
    <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{gestionCat.deleteAction(c)}" />
</p:dataTable>
```

Based on what I've read, I was under the impression that a converter was always necessary with the use of complex objects and `dataTable`s. Does the `dataTable` component use a predefined `Converter`?

Comment: I am newbie to jsf and i am trying to understand how it works.I don't get it how i can send an object using HTTP:Since it's impossible,the only way that i see is by using Convereter.So yes,like you hv said,i though a String representing the object will be sent instead of the object then converted in an object.(and i am not using any converter !)

Comment: I tried something close to what you suggested,,it works,so it has nothing to do with datatable,it's a common behavior for all component in facelet...I don't get it,when u said that it's not being sent via HTTP (and so no converter is needed),via what it can be sent ? and what actually is being sent ?

Comment: aha,i get it now (or at least what i think),so there is no object is being sent,an ID to identify the command link that have been clicked and the application server can then execute the mentionned action with the appropriate parametre...Thx a lot for your patience and help.